# Eigen and MKL 11.2

Tags: c++, eigen, flags, intel-mkl

I'm trying to link Eigen to MKL 11.2
I have the latest stable release of Eigen 3.2.4. However even so [this bug](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=874) was still present, which I fixed with the latest source from the Eigen repository.

Now when I try to compile using the given flags from [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor/), more specifically:

```
-O3 -std=c++11 -m64 -I/opt/intel/mkl/include
```

I still get the following error:

```
main.cpp:(.text._ZmlIN5Eigen6MatrixIdLin1ELin1ELi0ELin1ELin1EEEER6ADNodeIT_ES6_
S6_[_ZmlIN5Eigen6MatrixIdLin1ELin1ELi0ELin1ELin1EEEER6ADNodeIT_ES6_S6_]+0x3f4)
: undefined reference to `dgemm'
```

I'm not an expert on C++ linking and etc, can anyone advise me what more should I add to the compiler flags?

Answer (score 0):

You got the compiler-phase options, but failed to add as well the linker-phase options provided by the form you referred.  For me, it says something as

```
-L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64 -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core
-lmkl_sequential -lpthread -lm
```

Note the `-l` options adding the libraries, and the `-L` option telling the linker where to find them if they are in non-standard places.